# Porting X/Motif GUI application to Windows using wxWidgets

Tags: windows, user-interface, solaris, wxwidgets, motif

Is it possible to port an application built in X/Motif GUI on Solaris platform to Windows using wxWidgets? If so, is it easier to port to wxWidgets than other GUI builders like QT or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to port a Motif application to wxWidgets, but you won't be able to keep much code intact. In other words, this will be a non-trivial undertaking -- but this will be true whether you use wx, Qt or anything else (but using a portable framework does seem like a better idea if you have Unix background but need it to work under Windows).